# How to get route segments for a given coordinate

Tags: maps, gis, openstreetmap

I have X,Y coordinates reported by GPS, via IoT from a vehicle.

I need to identify route information, including route segment, that corresponds to that coordinate. Like this:

```
GetRouteInfo(X, Y) --> (RouteId, SegmentId)
```

Since the number of points (coordinates) is huge, I would prefer to do this in offline mode, avoiding network traffic.

My question is: are there any recommended libraries for performing this?

Comment: Route could be anything - Do you have a list of precomputed routes, defined as a polyline or similar?

Comment: _RouteId_ is a network element like road id or a street id, defined in an existing traffic network map, e.g. OSM.

The idea is to determine the element segment which the point belongs to.